# Browser thinks that the HTML file is a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing a website using NodeJS and Express. After specifying a link with 2 route parameters:

```
app.get('/game/:port/:player/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/game/game.html'));
})
```

-the result is a blank white page.
Looking at DevTools, I saw the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'    game.js:1`. It looks like the browser is interpreting the html file as a JavaScript file! I think this is because the browser tries to fetch the js and css files from `/game/(portnumber)/(playernumber)` instead of from `/game`. And the css shows up as the actual HTML file:

[image]

However, another route that I have with only 1 route parameter works just fine! I am still relatively new to Express so I don't really understand how fetching directories works.

Is there any way to fix this directory error without manually specifying every single path in which there are HTML files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Express. It is basic URL resolution.

The browser will request `/game/3561/2` and get an HTML document back

That document will tell it to load `./game.js` which it will resolve to
`/game/3561/game.js` (since a URL starting with a `.` means "resolve the path from current directory").

That isn't the URL of your JS file, so you get an HTML document instead — where `:player` is `game.js`.

You need to write the actual URL to your JS file in the `src` attribute.

Comment: So what should the URL be? I tried using /home/pi/dir/game/game.js (server file is in 'dir' directory) but the result is the same. What should it be relative to?

Comment: I don't know, none of the code you've shown will serve that JS file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `express.static` middleware to specify a public directory your clients have access to:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))

http://localhost:3000/static/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/static/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/static/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/static/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/static/hello.html
```